# Is it possible to have a OneToOneField in Django that's only null=True in one direction?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to create a `OneToOneField` in Django that is only `null=True` in one direction?

Ex:

```py
class Building(models.Model):
    ...

class Roof(models.Model):
    building = models.OneToOneField(...)
    ...
```

A building doesn't technically need to have a roof. Plenty of unfinished buildings don't have them. But you can't have a roof without a building.

Also, a building can only have one roof, and a roof can only be on one building, hence `OneToOneField`.

Comment: That's already supported right? You can have a building with no entries in roof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models as setup already accomplishes that.

```py
b1 = models.Building.objects.create()  # no error
b2 = models.Building.objects.create()  # no error
r1 = models.Roof.objects.create()      # violates null constraint

psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "building_id" of 
relation "users_roof" violates not-null constraint

r2 = models.Roof.objects.create(building=b2) # no error
```

You're left with `Building b1` with no `Roof`, and `Building b2` with `Roof r2`.

Keep in mind that `OneToOneField` is not "symmetric", in the sense that it matters which of the two models you put the field in.  With your models as defined, you will basically end up with an underlying `Building` database table with no mention of `Roof`, and a `Roof` table that contains a column with a `foreign key` (with a `unique` constraint) back to `Building`.  That is why creating a `Building` does not require specifying a `Roof`, but creating a `Roof` requires specifying the associated `Building`.

Comment: `Keep in mind that OneToOneField is not "symmetric", in the sense that it matters which of the two models you put the field in` - I just assumed it was symmetric. I thought I read somewhere that it was. I think it must have just said that you can create the `OneToOneField` on either model, but not that it was symmetric. Thanks for clearing that up